# Python dispy - keep package names for dependencies

Tags: python, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, dispy

Is there a way to keep the package names for python modules that are transmitted via dispy's depends feature?
That would allow using packages/modules in the same way when called with and without a dispy context.

Simple Example:

Module mypackage.dispytestDepends:

```
def myFun():
    return "Foo"
```

main module as I'd like it to have (doesn't work):

```
def dependsFunTask(): #works only when called without dispy
    import mypackage.dispytestDepends 
    ret = mypackage.dispytestDepends.myFun()
    return ret

import dispy
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cluster = dispy.JobCluster(dependsFunTask,depends = mypackage.dispytestDepends) # doesn't work
    job = cluster.submit()
    output = job()
    print output ### output is None
    mypackage.dependsFunTask() # works
```

Working, yet ugly version, since I have lots of code that would have to be rewritten:

```
def dependsFunTask(): #only works when called through dispy
    import dispytestDepends
    ret = dispytestDepends.myFun()
    return ret

import dispy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cluster = dispy.JobCluster(dependsFunTask,depends = mypackage.dispytestDepends) # works
    job = cluster.submit()
    output = job()
    print output ### output is "Foo"
    dependsFunTask() # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work now with the current version of dispy. See also https://github.com/pgiri/dispy/issues/43.